# Angular 2 $http.get with custom header cause 400

Tags: http, angular, ionic2

I'm using angular 2, and I(m trying to do a simple request with a custom header:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'App-Auth': 'myAuthToken' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.get(this.globalVars.serverUrl+'/api/Users/'+69, options).map(res => res.json());
```

Then I receive a 400 Bad request from my server (owin with wep api 2) for Get request (Options request return OK(200)). It work fine when no custom header is provides.

Comment: You're not passing the options to the http() call. You're passing them as second argument of map(). Anyway, we can't guess why your server returns a 400. Look at the server logs, at the body of the 400 response, at the server code.

Comment: I've update the code, but result is the same

Answer (score 0):

The cross-origin server is likely not permitting the *App-Auth* header. Make sure that the cross-origin server's *Access-Control-Request-Headers* includes *App-Auth*.

If you do not have control over the cross-origin server, you will not be able to use the *App-Auth* header.

> Access-Control-Request-Headers - A comma-delimited list of non-simple
>   headers that are included in the request.
>
> ref: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: How do you know it's cross origin request?

Comment: Because in the original post, the author identifies that the Options request is returning a 200 status. The only time the browser passes the Options request prior to the Get request is when the request is going "cross-origin".

Answer (score 0):

It as noting to do with the way I was doing the request by with a mistake on my server. Sorry

Comment: perhaps since the community took the time to help you find an answer to your problem, you could share with us what your solution was?